# Cannot edit custom field

Tags: custom-field

I cannot edit a custom made field even though I have made it visible and editable to my current user profile. If you have a look at the first image here, it clearly shows the Word Count Limit field to be visible.

[image: Word count limit is visible]

However, when I click the edit button to be able to enter a value in the field, the field disappears.

[image: Disappeared]

Could anybody give me some guidance?

Comment: Did you override your edit button to have a visualforce page for your edit screen or is it a standard edit layout ?

Comment: what i the data type of that field? it seems custom ui. is that correct?

Comment: @valkarth Are you created new custom page or salesforce standard page your using

Comment: @VijayGanji When I click edit, it redirects me to a URL which begins with https://c.ap8.visual.force.com/apex/..... Therefore, I would think that this redirects me to a visualforce page.

Comment: @Himanshu The data type of Word Count field is Number.

Comment: @NITHESHK Clicking on redirects me to a visualforce page.

Comment: as you answered in another comment you have visualforce page for edit functionality. You need to add that field in that VF page.

Comment: I have found the Visualforce page which is used to override the edit button. I looked at the code of this visualforce page and tried to edit the code to also contain the Word_Count_Limit__c field. However, it resulted in a <code>SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Essay.Word_Count_Limit__c</code> error.

Comment: I know that this means that some piece of code requested Essay, but has not accounted for Word_Count_Limit__c. Is there a process to find where that SOQL command is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comments, I understand that you have overridden the edit button with a visual force page.

To fix your issue, you need to check few things

- Check the FLS for Word Count Limit field for the profile from which you are trying to access the page. It should be Visible i.e. the profile should have read write access.
- Check in your visualforce page, if you have included the `<apex:inputField>` for Word Count Limit field, if not, then you will have to include it.
- If you are using a custom controller, then check in your controller if you are quering the Word Count Limit field i.e. check in SOQL query to include that field. (If you are using custom controller, then you will have to check all the above mentioned points. If you are using standard controller, then you will have to verify first two points)

You can go through [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals) trailhead module for understanding basics of visualforce and controllers.